# Display CPU cores usage in percentage without using top

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, command-line

I am using java to run a command on linux. Since top is an interactive command and need to press 1 to get the info of all the cpu(s) so I cannot use that. So I am using the following command to get the cpu(s) info:

```
cat /proc/stat|grep "^cpu[0-9]* ";sleep 3;cat /proc/stat|grep "^cpu[0-9]* "
```

I am getting the output as :

```
cpu  4673683 193 832132 1544221346 142352 1220 171760 0 0
cpu0 2473973 90 524817 769734476 73628 1124 158588 0 0
cpu1 2199709 103 307315 774486870 68723 95 13171 0 0
cpu  4673683 193 832133 1544221744 142352 1220 171760 0 0
cpu0 2473974 90 524817 769734674 73628 1124 158588 0 0
cpu1 2199709 103 307315 774487069 68723 95 13171 0 0
```

Now my problem is how to get the percentage out of it as top command is showing.

```
 Cpu0  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :  0.0%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
```

Comment: Can't you use `time` ?

Comment: sorry, din't get you. U mean time command

Answer (score 1):

Try the `mpstat` utility from the `sysstat` package:

```
mpstat -u -P ALL
```

Output on CentOS host (virtual host with 1 virtual cpu):

```
Linux 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64 (testhost.testdomain)   08/11/2015  _x86_64_    (1 CPU)

10:03:57 AM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
10:03:57 AM  all    0.21    0.05    0.29    0.04    0.00    0.13    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.28
10:03:57 AM    0    0.21    0.05    0.29    0.04    0.00    0.13    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.28
```

Output on Ubuntu host:

```
Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (myhost)    11-08-15    _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

10:05:37     CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
10:05:37     all    3,34    0,04    1,16    0,13    0,08    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   95,25
10:05:37       0    2,81    0,06    1,93    0,13    0,11    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   94,96
10:05:37       1    3,94    0,03    0,78    0,10    0,03    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   95,13
10:05:37       2    3,31    0,02    1,21    0,16    0,07    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   95,24
10:05:37       3    3,31    0,05    0,73    0,14    0,10    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   95,68
```

Comment: I cannot install new package  mpstat it is not provided by default. I am using Centos

Answer (score 0):

May be try like this:

```
 top -b -n 1 | grep -i "^cpu"
```

Following is output on my machine:

```
wbzz@mambet:~$ top -b -n 1 | grep -i "^cpu"
Cpu0  : 10.5%us,  4.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 82.4%id,  1.6%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  : 44.5%us, 15.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 40.2%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  : 43.8%us, 18.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 37.7%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  : 45.1%us, 14.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 40.3%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
```

This works on slackware-current. On CentOS machine need to change grep expression to:

```
top -b -n 1 | grep -i "^%cpu"
```

Comment: Could you please relate and explain how your answer is solving the OP ?

Comment: By default when you run top program it runs interactively. But you can run it in batch mode (using -b option). And then parse required information. So you will get same result like running top program.

Comment: Have you tried it & got any successful results ?

Comment: Yes. Result on my machine like following: Cpu(s): 25.2%us,  9.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 63.7%id,  1.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.6%si,  0.0%st

Comment: When you are doing a `grep -i "^cpu"` , it doesn't start with `cpu`, it starts with `%Cpu(s)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26827/discussion-between-neuron-and-murad-tagirov).

Comment: I think u have saved top configuration settings after pressing 1 to ~/.toprc file. so by default it is showing all the cpu(s). In my system its just showing: Cpu(s):  0.9%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.6%id,  0.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st

Comment: Yes. Because you can not change this option on command startup.

Comment: I tried the Centos command as well its not working